# Workflow Error: Coercion Failed: Input cannot be null for this coercion

Tags: 2010, workflow, designer-workflow, lookup-column

I have a workflow that is assigning a task based on a lookup value. This workflow runs successfully the first time then fails on subsequent attempts. Here's how the data looks:

**Look Up**

```
 Title     Contacts
-------   ----------
 Plant1    John Smith; Jane Smith
 Plant2    John Doe; Jane Doe
```

**Workflow List**

```
 Title    Desc    Plant
-------  ------  -------
Test 1    asdf    Plant1
```

In the workflow, the plant contacts are found like this:

```
 Retrieve Data
---------------
 Plants -> Contacts as Email Semicolon Delimited

 Find Data
---------------
 Plants:Title = CurrentItem:Plant
```

Why would it work once and then fail? I have isolated this as the issue because if I hard code a Plant Title it works every time.

Comment: Is it failing the second time for the same list item?

Comment: The workflow is initiated by item creation. If I create the 2nd item with the exact same values, it will fail.

Comment: So can we isolate this issue saying if duplicate items are created the workflow fails?

Comment: The issue is assigning a task using the associative value. If I do the same process but send an email instead; it works everytime. It doesn't matter if it's a Approval Process or Custom task both fail after first time.

Comment: Correction looks like the WF intermittently fails even on the email action.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue just add wait until the look up value not empty in the start of the workflow preferred to be the first line :) Hope it help

[image]

Comment: Can you please improve your answer, with some more brief description. One liner may not be helpful for other visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Add Required field to Look up field. Or Minimum we need to select one value for Lookup Field. Then it won't show error.